# Debian 10 Wifi Problem with MT7630e

Tags: debian, wifi, asus

I installed Debian 10 on an Asus notebook. As soon as I installed the Wi-Fi was not working. 
My WIFI chip is

```
MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
```

I installed the package firmware-misc-nonfree but Debian still didn't found the WiFi chip so as suggested in many forum I installed this driver https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E.
As soon as I installed it everything worked fine.

The problems started when I try to connect to another Wifi. The network manager start searching forever a new Wifi using 100% of one core of the CPU without possibility to stop the process(I tried all possible command for stopping the NetworkManager, like stopping the service and kill the process). I tried to wait until it stop but after hours it never stop.

I tried to reboot and shutdown multiple time and the only way to make the Wifi working again is to shoutdown the notebook by hold down the power button.

How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT**: The workaround I'm using consist to install the driver(the one from Github) at startup and uninstall before shutdown. It's not a solution but it's the only way to not hold down the power button.

Answer (score 1):

Your best chance is to abandon your current driver source, since it's declared in search of a new maintainer ( https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E/issues/90 ) and is using an old code dump from vendor.

Instead, you should rely on the newly available upstream linux driver available since [kernel 4.20](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/MT76x0E.html):

> CONFIG_MT76x0E: MediaTek MT76x0E (PCIe) support General informations
>
> The Linux kernel configuration item CONFIG_MT76x0E:
>
> ```
> prompt: MediaTek MT76x0E (PCIe) support
> type: tristate
> depends on: ( CONFIG_MAC80211 ) && ( CONFIG_PCI )
> defined in drivers/net/wireless/mediatek/mt76/mt76x0/Kconfig
> found in Linux kernels: 4.20, 5.0–5.1, 5.2-rc+HEAD
> modules built: mt76x0e
> ```
>
> Help text
>
> This adds support for MT7610/MT7630-based wireless PCIe devices.
>   Hardware PCI
>
> Numeric ID (from LKDDb) and names (from pci.ids) of recognized
>   devices:
>
> ```
> vendor: 14c3 ("MEDIATEK Corp."), device: 7630 ("MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter")
> vendor: 14c3 ("MEDIATEK Corp."), device: 7650
> ```

Debian 10 will ship with kernel 4.19. As long as it's frozen sid/unstable will only provide upgrades for Debian 10, so also only provides 4.19. You can use an experimental 5.0.x package, from [Debian experimental](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianExperimental) (which isn't updated often), or manage to compile a Debianized kernel using https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/linux (steps aren't that trivial), or simply compile a vanilla kernel. It might one day appear in [Linux backports](https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) for 4.19, but I don't know more than giving the previous link.

There are anyway other issues currently with this driver, for example [somebody repoted problems when system is woken up from sleep](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202563).

Good luck!